# Configure storage of WhatsApp media files

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, storage, media-files

I want to configure whether WhatsApp stores media in my phone.
I found many links like
[this](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/how-stop-whatsapp-saving-photos-on-android-3471900/)
and
[this](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/features/whatsapp-how-to-stop-auto-downloading-and-saving-of-photos-582469)
which point to
Main Chat Screen -> Three dots -> Settings -> Chats -> Media auto-download,
 or the like.
But I do not have such menu.
I see what is shown in the image below.

**What can I do to select WhatsApp media storage?**

PS: I am currently dealing with a WhatsApp account setup in Parallel Space. I have no main WhatsApp account setup, and I cannot set it up now to test it. But I doubt this affects the menus available in WhatsApp.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Chat Screen -> Three dots -> Settings -> Data Usage -> Media Auto Download** [image: **see this screen shot from my whatsapp 2.17.19.**]